# Replace each ? in the expression with a digit or operator

Tags: calculation-puzzle, lateral-thinking, formation-of-numbers

In the following expression, replace each `?` with either a digit or an operator:

`8?5+??5-9?+3`

so that it can evaluate to:

`57883`

Comment: Which operators can be used?

Comment: May we insert brackets "(" and ")" at arbitrary places in the expression?

Comment: Is `8!5` permissible as "eight factorial times five", or is it invalid? Is `5+--5` permissible as "five plus the negation of the negation of five" or is it invalid? Is `8.5 + 0.5` permissible, or is `.` not an operator? Is `005` a valid value, or are leading zeroes forbidden? Should the expression be evaluated left to right, or using PEMDAS rules, or something else?

Comment: The closest I can get is `8/5+9**5-9**+3 = 58321.6`. I think I'm going to admit defeat now.

Comment: @xnor I can't really answer that without giving away the answer!

Comment: @Gamow You may not insert anything, you may only replace the question marks.

Comment: @Kevin I would allow `8!5`, `5+--5`, and `8.5+0.5`, but please see the edit I just made.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage If you want to continue looking for a mathematical solution, you can also use `^` as an exponent operator. (But look at the edit I just made.)

Comment: @pacoverflow I was using Python, where `^` is the logical XOR operator and `**` is used for exponentiation (as in the expression I quoted above). In fact I tried every combination of `0`-`9` plus `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `%`, `(`, `)`, `**`, `~`, `<<` and `>>`. Nothing gives the required answer.

Comment: A vague idea: Since it is a brainteaser, perhaps we must read the puzzle upside down, so that "57883" becomes "EBBLS". (No idea how to go on.)

Comment: My answer uses previously defined and well accepted operators.

Comment: Are we limited to decimal? -- Can I use Hex?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore You can try, I'll be interested to see if there's a hex solution.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Going for a "pure math" solution, I got `8^5+7!5-90+3=57881`. So close.

Comment: @KSmarts Good job.  I structured the puzzle to see if someone would come up with that solution and then say that the question contained a mistake - that it should contain "+5" at the end. :)

Comment: I think this puzzle contains a mistake. It should be "+5" at the end. :)

Comment: Is intentionally including a mistake in a puzzle good form?

Comment: @IanMacDonald It's only a mistake if KSmarts' answer is the correct answer, but it's not the correct answer.

Comment: @pacoverflow: so then your comment to him was sarcastic? This does not come through in text.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Sorry if that wasn't clear.  But I did mention in an edit that I'm looking for a non-mathematical answer.

Comment: @pacoverflow: Can you give an example of a "previously defined and well accepted operators" that is not mathematical in nature?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I don't think I can without giving away the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was thinking of "non-mathematical solution" that would have well-defined and accepted operators, and that telling which operators are acceptable, and one that came to my mind was that

> evaluate here means "matches a regular expression", and the solution is for example `8*5+7[5-9]+3`

Comment: You got it, great job! :)  Also accepted would be `8?5+7[5-9]+3`

Comment: But then the first `?` would have not been replaced ;-)

Comment: The wording of this question is misleading. A regular expression does not **evaluate *to*** a matching value, it **validates** a value.

Comment: Considering that a regular expression specifies a formal language, a set of possible words that *match* that regular expression, I’d agree that “evaluating to” does not really work well here. (Also, those symbols are not really operators in regular expressions…) But still, nice puzzle.

Comment: Interesting puzzle, but those characters are metacharacters.

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's why I specifically wrote "**can** evaluate to" in the question, since the regex can evaluate to many values.

Comment: @overloading True, but many people call them operators too: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=regular+expression+operators

Comment: @pacoverflow: No, the regex does not evaluate to many values. It validates many values. A regex is not a statement that evaluates to anything; it is a unary operator that takes an argument and produces a boolean result.

Answer (score 2):

> I define the `+` operator as an operation that takes two somethings and returns 57883. Then I can insert whatever I want for the placeholders. The final `+3` will give my the result.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't originally clarify in the question that the operator must be a previously-defined and well-accepted operator, nor that an operator necessarily equates to a single character, my solution is:

> `8?5+??5-9?+3`
>  `885+475-9r+3`
>
>  Where I have defined the following operators:
>  `+` operator: `(xyz)+(abc)` : concatenate with inner-digit addition providing digit result: `xy(z+a)bc`.
>  `-` operator: `xyz-y` : delete digit providing digit result: `xz`.
>  `r+` operator: `xyzr+a` : reverse the digits and concatenate without addition providing digit result: `zyxa`.

This works out as:

> `885+475-9r+3`
>  `88975-9r+3`
>  `8875r+3`

`57883`

Comment: interesting way of thinking, but the question contains only 1 space behind the 9, you've put a digit ànd an operator behind it

Comment: Oh geez. I copied it from the question wrong when I started working on it. :S Gimmie a second. I'm sure there's a small tweak to make this still work.

Comment: I’m fine with `-` and `r+` but if your `+` operator is acceptable, then mine is too :P

Comment: @poke: I never claimed yours wasn't acceptable; it's just a little too restrictive. Defining an operator to always return a constant result isn't much use outside of the specific context of this puzzle.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Oh no, my comment wasn’t really directed at you ;) (But yeah, you’re right, but still… how does a mathematician catch a lion? He gets in a cage and defines it as outside ;P)

Comment: @poke The mathematician recalls that he has seen a lion in captivity. He makes a claim that since someone has caught a lion, a solution exists QED.